# Store Statistical Data to Mysql with CronJob or Run a function to pull it every time?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, statistics

I made an eCommerce application in PHP, I need to gather statistical data such as "New Customer, New Orders, Open Orders, Open Issues, etc.." and display it in the admin dashboard which we visit a lot thru out the day, now I have SQL "Functions" in PHP to retrieve the corresponding data, the problem is that for instance to get the "New Customers" alone the SQL scripts takes a bit to finish execution since to get the "New Customer" number it has to go thru all the orders and customers and based on a logic it determines the amount of new customers.

Instead of running the SQL scripts every time we visit the admin Dashboard would it be better to have a cronJob run in set intervals and store the results to Database table directly and from the dashboard we would pull the Statistics directly from database?

I would greatly appreciate any other suggestions!

Comment: try adding indexes to your tables and optimize queries, shouldnt be taking longer than a second

Comment: something like `select custom_number from orders where order_date >= '$report_cutoff_date'` shouldn't take long to run unless you've got a few billion/trillion orders.

Comment: even with million/billion records if properly indexed and optmized query shouldnt take long. I have 15 million records in few of my tables that join same amount of rows and takes less than a second to return data

Comment: I'm not sure what columns to index to make the query faster below is the query I run to get new customers http://pastebin.com/bDyJHaAZ

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the most reasonable way to solve this problem is generate stat data scheduled & background.

You can try follow the following steps:

a) first create a Statistics table for stored results.

b) create a php script (assume CRON.PHP) that generate stat data and store it into that table.

c) use a dedicated server or a 24-hours-online PC, set up a line in crontab:

```
0 5 * * * curl http://YOUR_HOST/CRON.PHP
```

that will generate data every 5 o'clock morning. and you can pull these data directly from dashboard.